# Mojolicious suddenly stopped working from one minute to the next

Tags: perl, mojolicious

A few days ago, I installed the Mojolicious package on my local machine because I needed to implement a websocket in one of my Perl programs on my production server. It installed without a problem and I was able to run a simple test script:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::IOLoop;

# Open WebSocket
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

$ua->insecure(1); # Otherwise the handshake will fail

$ua->websocket('wss://some.server.com' => sub {
  my ($ua, $tx) = @_;

  # Check if WebSocket handshake was successful
  unless( $tx->is_websocket ) {
    print "Handshake failed!\n";
    return;
  }

  # Wait for WebSocket to be closed
  $tx->on(finish => sub {
    my ($tx, $code, $reason) = @_;
    print "WebSocket closed with status $code.\n";
  });

  # Close WebSocket after receiving one message
  $tx->on(message => sub {
    my ($tx, $msg) = @_;
    print "WebSocket message: $msg\n";
    $tx->finish;
  });

  # Send a message to the server
  print "Sending...\n";
  $tx->send("Hi there!");

});

# Start event loop if necessary
Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;

print "Done!\n";
```

I was testing this on a server which had a small problem with its certificate which is the reason I added this line:

```perl
$ua->insecure(1); # Otherwise the handshake will fail
```

When I finally got it working by adding this line, I installed Mojolicious on my production server, copied over the above perl script, and it ran perfectly fine there also.

I then went back to my script on my local machine and ran it again. Much to my surprise, I now got an error message saying:

> Can't locate object method "insecure" via package "Mojo::UserAgent" at test009.pl line 14,  line 2231.

I reinstalled Mojolicious a few times, but each time I got this error when I ran the script. Removing the line just causes the script to do nothing at all. It doesn't print the "Handshake failed" message, nor any other message. Not even the "Done!" message.

It looks like it simply stops right after `websocket()` is called...

I'm at a loss now. I have absolutely no clue why it isn't working anymore. Nothing changed to my Perl environment on my local machine...

Here is some more info on my local machine

- Windows 7 Pro 64bit SP1
- ActivePerl 5.16.2
- Mojolicious 6.64

Can anyone offer some tips as to what has happened? Or preferably, how to get it working again?

Comment: Your Mojolicious is too old. `insecure` [was only added in version 7.80](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/SRI/Mojolicious-8.0#L135-141).

Comment: At this point I'd like to give kudos to Perl modules for having actual usable change logs. This isn't the first time I've identified a problem just by reading through a list of changes in each version of some module.

Comment: @melpomene how is it possible that an older version apparently installed itself (without me doing anything) over a newer version? `insecure` worked this afternoon. Also, according to my package manager, Mojolicious 6.64 is the newest version available... This is very odd...

Comment: Wait, now I'm no longer sure `insecure` *ever* worked on my local machine.

Answer (score 5):

From [the Mojolicious change log](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/SRI/Mojolicious-8.0#L135-141):

> 7.80  2018-05-20
>
> - Many users expected that Mojo::UserAgent would verify all TLS certificates
>     by default. Unfortunately that has not been the case so far, but will change
>     with this release in an effort to strengthen security. By default
>     Mojo::UserAgent will now reject all invalid TLS certificates. To return to
>     the previous behavior you can use the new `insecure` attribute.
>
>   ```
>   $ua->insecure(1);
>   ```

`insecure` is new in 7.80. Your Mojolicious 6.64 is too old.

You said

> I reinstalled Mojolicious a few times, but each time I got this error when I ran the script.

Either you didn't install the latest version or your script somehow still picked up the old version (a directory search order problem?).

If you want to keep your code compatible (and insecure) between both old and new versions,

```
$ua->insecure(1) if $ua->can('insecure');
```

should work.

Comment: It's probably best just to `use Mojo::UserAgent 7.80` rather than have it fail silently.

Comment: @Borodin In this case it would succeed silently. Older versions were insecure by default; `$ua->insecure(1)` is the backwards compatibility hack in newer versions.